# How to get the last commit of an specific file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, gitpython

I tried with `GitPython`, but I am just getting the *actual* commit git hash.

```
import git
repo = git.Repo(search_parent_directories=True)
repo.head.commit.hexsha
```

But, for trazability I want to store the git commit hash of an specific file, i.e. the equivalent of this command (using `git`)

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%h -- experiments/test.yaml
```

Is it possible to achive with `GitPython`?

Answer (score 1):

An issue like [how do I get sha key for any repository' file.](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/778) points to [the Tree object](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#the-tree-object), as providing an access for recursive traversal of git trees, with access to all meta-data, including the SHA1 hash.

```
self.assertEqual(tree['smmap'], tree / 'smmap')          # access by index and by sub-path
for entry in tree:                                         # intuitive iteration of tree members
    print(entry)
blob = tree.trees[0].blobs[0]                              # let's get a blob in a sub-tree
assert blob.name
```

`blob.hexsha` would be the SHA1 of the blob.

Comment: The `blob` s `hexsha` is not the same that the commit `sha`

Comment: @nanounanue True: from the blob, you need to get back to its tree (which you have), and then to the commit (like repo.heads.master.commit.tree). So you need to perform that blob search for the tree of every commit (of a branch) to check the blob.name and print the commit sha.